# Excel - need to repetitevely enter many small sized data in excel. Looking for the ways to automate/simplify

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have lots of repetitive data entry tasks at hand. All rows will be of a similar structure however, each row consists of 10 entries of a 0 to 24 number range, and its not necessary that all 10 entries are used in all rows. The only thing I could say certainly, that entry 2 will be larger than entry 3, and entry 4 is larger than entry 5.

I have tried dropdown lists, but it takes too much time. I need something like buttons (even the 24 buttons are ok), to click and quickly enter the certain value into the current selection. Time is of essense.

So, in my ideal speradsheet, clicking ANY(!) button would make an entry into the first entry area and clicking the second buttin would be the next entry area an so on.

Any other ideas, VBA or a code would be more than welcome.

Please, help.

Thank you.

Thanks for the comments, I will add some visual info too.
Basically, I am going to enter data like this:

[image]

The only reason I mentioned the larger and smaller number is that, perhaps I could gain more time if I use a formula, because once you entered the first number (in above case, 24), the second number must bee a difference between 24 and one of the earlier brought digits(in this case, 14:)

And these entries, I must make probably 100 of them at one go, few tousands in a day.

By typing, yes, I could train myself to type it but, I need to swap keyboard and mouse over several times, very inonvenient and frustruating, time consuming too.

Comment: Hi @SKYTTEN please [edit] your post & add some sample data, then I'll show you how to works with  Data Entry, using VBA macro. Also, what is the logic behind larger number than it's previous entry ?

Comment: I don't see how creating 24 buttons will speed you up. Using the 10-key on the computer keyboard requires finger dexterity and visual focus on the numbers you are reading. However, using buttons would require you to additionally switch visual focus between the list you are reading and the buttons you are clicking on.

Comment: My point of reference is my ability to record about 17,000 keystrokes on a 10-key. I wouldn't peg this as extraordinary as my typing speed is around 60 WPM. Anyway, this would translate probably down to about 6 seconds per 10 entries.